# update php var with js var from ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to update php `$questNumber` with the incremented javascript `questNum` with jQuery `$.get()`

Console.log tells me that the js `questNum` var is being incremented correctly.

But `echo "testing..." . $questNumber;` outputs `1` even after I've incremented the value on the JS side. This means the updated value is not being sent to `$questNumber` to update the database, and return the appropriate new set of values to the javascript side.

JavaScript:

```
/*Check player sentence input to see if grammar is correct*/
function submitMe() {
    var input = document.getElementById('textBox').value;
    log(questNum);
    if ($.trim(input) == getSentence(questNum)) {
        $("#responseVerify").html("Great job");
        $("#textBox").val("").trigger("change");
        //post successful quest to Quests.php, which will increment questcount there, and get new vocab words
        questNum++;
        log(questNum);
        $.get("php/Quests.php", { "_questNum" : questNum},
            function() {
                $(".wordBank_Words").empty();
                $.each(wordsArray, function(key, value) {           
                    $(".wordBank_Words").append("<div class='bank-word' word='" + key + "' ><b>" + key + "</b>: " + value + "</div>");
                });
            });
        }
    else {
        $("#responseVerify").html("Keep going...");
    }
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    //if user's input is correct, increment task number, get next vocabulary
    include 'DbConnect.php';
    $questNumber = (isset($_GET['_questNum']) ? ($_GET['_questNum']) : 1);  
    echo "testing..." . $questNumber;

    $qry = 
     "SELECT t.*, v.* 
     FROM task t 
     INNER JOIN vocabtask vt ON (t.id = vt.taskid)
     INNER JOIN vocab v ON (v.id = vt.vocabid)
     WHERE vt.taskid = " . $questNumber;

    $sql = $mysqli->query($qry);

    $wordsArray = array();
    while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row['chinese'];
        $wordsArray[$row['chinese']] = $row['english'];
    }
    echo "testing..." . $questNumber;
    mysqli_close($mysqli);  
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'> var wordsArray = " . json_encode($wordsArray) . "; </script>";
?>
```

HTML:

```
        <!--ROW 3: RESPONSE-->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span12">
                <!--Select a word shown and it gets added to the input box-->
                Create sentence:

                <input type="text" id="textBox"  value="" />
                <br/>
                <button onclick="submitMe()" id="testButton" >Submit Response </button>
                <br/>

                <i><span id="responseVerify"></span></i><br />
                <div class="wordBank_Headings">Word Bank:
                    <span class="wordBank_Words"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="wordBank_Headings">Hint:
                    <span class="wordBank_Hint"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="wordBank_Headings">New Words:
                    <span class="new"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: echo your $_GET['_questNum'] in top of the page and show me

Comment: The rest of your Javascript would help since the variable in question appears to be global in nature

Comment: @NathanSrivi that gives `Undefined index: _questNum`

Comment: @Growler well there's your problem.  You aren't passing the variable to the PHP

Comment: @Deryck yes I know, but the $.get ajax looks correct, so I'm not sure what's the problem

Comment: `$questNumber = (isset($_GET['_questNum']) ? ($_GET['_questNum']) : 1);` remove that last `)` and the `(` just before the last `$_GET` and add a `)` before the `?`

Comment: dammit just do this:  `$questNumber = (isset($_GET['_questNum'])) ? $_GET['_questNum'] : 1;`

Comment: @Deryck okay. I did that but it did not fix it. It might be because I am including the `Quests.php` file in the top of my Game.php main file. And it could be running the script as null?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46571/discussion-between-growler-and-deryck)

Comment: @Growler Run and Show your ajax url like this localhost/sitename/php/Quests.php?_questNum=5 in your browser directly.

Comment: What value you got it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this ajax format

```
$.ajax({                                  
        type: "GET",   //method
        url:"php/Quests.php", //your ajax page        
        data:"_questNum="+questNum,  //pass values to this data
        success: function(data){    //success function  
        alert('sasas');        
        }
```

Comment: Nathan, it's alerting succesfully, but it doesn't seem to be passing the var to php.